# Configuration System failed to initialize while trying to connect to web service

Tags: c#, android, web-services, xamarin

I have a Xamarin Android App, made with Visual Studio 2017, and a ASMX Web Service.

The Web Service is published and running in the web Sever, the App, when in Debug mode, connects and runs fine without errors.

When I generate the APK file and install it in other device I receive the following error when trying to log in (First time the app calls the Web Service).

```
Configuration system failed to initialize

System.TypeInitializationException: 
The type initializer for 'System.Uri' threw an exception. ---> 
System.TypeInitializationException: 
The type initializer for 'System.UriParser' threw an exception. ---> 
System.MissingMethodException:
Method not found: bool System.Runtime.Versioning.BinaryCompatibility.get_TargetsAtLeast_Desktop_V4_5()
--- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
 at (wrapper managed-to-native)
System.Object.__icall_wrapper_mono_generic_class_init(intptr)
 at System.Uri..cctor () [0x00000] in <988fa07610c94365ae6d295a6aa379fe>: 0
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.EnsureConfigurationSystem() [0x00022] in <673a29f4914b4711bafe0a24a4318f71>: 0
```

I already tried the most common answer for this error without any luck.

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings"
                  type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >

      <section name="DCSWhseWS.Properties.Settings"
               type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
               requirePermission="false" />

    </sectionGroup>
```

This is the Web.config I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings"
                  type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >

      <section name="DCSWhseWS.Properties.Settings"
               type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
               requirePermission="false" />

    </sectionGroup>

  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240" executionTimeout="1200"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
  </system.web>  
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnString" connectionString="Connection String"/>
    <add name="ConnStringTest" connectionString="Connection String for Testing"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

And this is how I call the Web Service from the Android App:

**Button:**

```
        private async void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                clsUser u = new clsUser();
                u = ServiceCalls.Login(txtUser.Text);

                if (txtPass.Text.Trim().ToUpper() == u.Password.ToUpper())
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
                    i.PutExtra("UserAccount", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(u));
                    StartActivity(i);
                    Finish();
                }
                else
                    RunOnUiThread(() =>
                    {
                        Alert.ShowAlert("Invalid Password. please verify.", this).Show();
                    });
            });
        }
```

**ServiceCalls.cs**

```
internal static clsUser Login(string UserCode)
{
    WhseWS.Whse obj = new WhseWS.Whse();
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<clsUser>(obj.Login(UserCode));
}
```

Again, this error doesn't happen when I'm debugging the app only when the APK is installed in any device.

**EDIT:**

This is the Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="DCS.Whse" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="Warehouse" android:icon="@drawable/logo"></application>
</manifest>
```

**EDIT 2:**

I'm still having the problem, I'm starting to think it has something to do with my web server, since it doesn't has a SSL Certificate. I will try to get one and see if that resolves the problem.

**EDIT 3:**

The SSL Certificate didn't solve the issue.

**EDIT 4:**

Now, if I dismiss the first error and try to log in again I get this error:

```
The method or operation is not implemented.
```

It works on DEBUG mode so, the Web Service is implemented.

Both errors happen when trying to make an instance of the Web Service:

```
WhseWS.Whse obj = new WhseWS.Whse();
```

Comment: do you have Internet permissions enabled in the manifest?  It is enabled by default in DEBUG mode, but not in Release

Comment: Yes, I do have it enabled

Comment: are you testing debug mode on the device also?  Are you sure there are no connectivity issues between your device and your server?

Comment: So far I have tested the app in DEBUG mode in two devices. It is working fine in both devices while in debug mode. not working in any device when the APK is installed

Comment: you might try disabling the linker in release mode - possibly something is getting stripped out that you need

Comment: Yes, it is set to none. VS didn't let me create the APK without the linker set to none.

Comment: That doesn't sound right.  I don't think it's related to your main problem, but the linker options are one of the main ways you can control the size of your APK in release mode

Comment: I don't think be a problem with connectivity permissions, can you post the code where you do the request to the server.

Comment: @Ivan-San I have edited the post with the code from the Login Button and the call to the Web Service

Comment: Make sure you have all the nuget packages updated

Comment: Ivan-San. I just updated all of them, generate a new APK and had the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Let's check some stuffs, you have internet permissions in **Project** -> **Properties** -> **Android Manifest**.

[image]

In **Android Options** set **Linking** to *SDK Assemblies Only*
[image]

Verify your solutions references and try to clean and rebuild all the solution before make the APK. 
Check this example from Microsoft where it explains how to use an [ASMX Web Service in Xamarin](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WebServices/TodoASMX), maybe it can be helpful.

Here's some code that I found to consume the [SOAP Web Service in Xamarin](http://www.nullskull.com/a/10476774/consuming-web-services-using-xamarin.aspx).

```
try
{
    WhseWS.Whse obj = new WhseWS.Whse();
    obj.Url = "http://yourIPAddress:Port#/xyz.asmx";
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<clsUser>(obj.Login(UserCode));
}
catch (Exception ex){
    Console.WriteLine("Exception : " + ex);
}
```

Comment: All of this is fine in the project, however I still have the same issue.

Comment: I think the problem is more with the web service, you need to verify it and you could use the methods of HttpClient with System.Net